# Wrong controller is being used for edit route ( using Laravel resource helper )

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I'm currently using laravel 5.4 and I have stumbled upon something I can't fix.

I'm currently trying to bind a route to a controller using the Laravel `resource` helper as such :
`Route::resource('campaigns', 'CampaignsController');`.

I correctly see my route being there when I do a `PHP artisan:route list`, I have all my CRUD endpoints tied to the appropriate controller function. Also, note that I'm currently doing that for all my route that need to be tied to a CRUD system ( what I'm working with is mostly form ) without any problem

With this being said, whenever I'm trying to edit a `Campaign`, I get an error : `Class App\Http\Controllers\Ads\Campaigns does not exist`

I do not know why it's trying to look for a `Campaigns` controller while I specify the `CampaignsController` controller. Everything is behaving correctly in campaigns route, except the edit one. Also, all my other routes have the same logic and never faced this problem.

Any idea why it is looking for the wrong Controller ?

Here's my namespace declaration and folder hierarchy, which is ok ( please note that the adsController has its routes declared the same way and is used the same way too )

[image]

[image]

here's my edit method

[image]

and here's the error

[image]

Comment: Can you also please post your full CampaignsController file? It may be looking at the right controller, but something inside the controller is not working right.

Comment: Class App\Http\Controllers\Ads\Campaigns does not exist. This is the error i'm getting. I dont think my CampaignController have any problem, and if it did we would'nt know because this isn't the Controller Laravel is trying to look for ! :/

Comment: I don't think it's the CampaignsController it can't find. I think it's hitting the right controller and right function, but something is broken within that function. Howeverwithout that code to verify, it's hard to tell. I'm going to guess that the edit function is trying to load a single campaign, but it's unable to find the right model.

Comment: Well the error is explicitly saying that it couldnt load the Campaign controller, so is there an error the way the error message is displayed too ?
I tried it with an empty edit function, only keeping the return statement with an existing and already used view, got the same problem.

Comment: Also i've already had problem with code from withing my controller's function and this is not the error message i'm usually facing.

Please not that adding `/edit` at the end of my route makes it work, but all my other routes doesn't need to end with `/edit`

Comment: Could you be missing a simple import statement at the top of your file? `use App\Campaigns` (or whatever the namespace of your `Campaigns` model is)

Comment: @milo526 updated my post

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). It's hard to read, prevents text-based searching, and lowers the overall presentation value of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite possible that you try to inject not existing class in your controller.

Take a look at controller constructor or edit route if you don't have something like this:

```
public function edit(Campaigns $campaigns)
{
}
```

and make sure you import Campaigns from valid namespace (probably it's not in `App\Http\Controllers\Ads` namespace.

If it doesn't help try to find in your `app` directory occurrences of `Ads\Campaigns` to see where it's used. Sometimes problem can be in completely different part of your application.

**EDIT**

Also make sure you didn't make any typo. In error you have `Campaigns` but your model is probably `Campaign` - is it possible that in one place you have extra `s` at the end?

Comment: i added screenshots in my original post.

Comment: @JorelAmthor Take a look at *EDIT* in my answer

Comment: All my other routes ( and their controller ) are fine and work flawlessly. Only the edit one is buggy.

Comment: @JorelAmthor Well, it's not fine. You have in error `Campaigns`. Do you have `Campaigns` class anywhere? If not, find the line where you are using `Campaigns` and fix it to `Campaign` probably

Comment: @JorelAmthor So you must have somewhere typo, in your error there is `App\Http\Controllers\Ads\Campaigns` so you must have somewhere typo and you try to use `Campaigns` instead of `Campaign`

Answer (score 0):

Try with Route::resource('campaigns', 'Ads\CampaignsController'); in your web.php file

Comment: the `route::resource` is prefixed + namespace with `ads` so this isnt where the issue lies. Once again all my other routes are 100% ok. i can create / read / delete without problem.

Comment: Do you have some get request before route::resource in same route group, with some slug param or something similar? Maybe that route is triggered before edit method in route::resource